# Fastest way of inserting many parent and child records

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database, bulkinsert

I've found this article helpful in doing batch inserts [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework), however, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of inserting records with child entities as well.

My entities are like this:

[image]

I've been experimenting with [BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) and it seems to improve performance a bit, however it is still about 60 seconds for about 40 records each having multiple child entities. I have cases where I'll need to insert thousands of records and it can get extremely slow. My code is as follows:

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)))
{
    using (var db = new MyDBContext())
    {
        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        var entities = db.ScenarioCategory.AddRange(categories);
        db.BulkInsert(entities);
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
     transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling both `AddRange` and `BulkInsert`? You should pick one of them, because they both do the same operation..

Comment: @SteveGreene From BulkInsert: "To combine bulk insert with DbContext, TransactionScope must be used."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

Here is the fastest way of inserting, updating, deleting, and merging. You can even make it easier and use BulkSaveChanges over SaveChanges.

```
// Using BulkSaveChanges
using (var db = new MyDBContext())
{
    db.ScenarioCategory.AddRange(categories);
    db.BulkSaveChanges();
}

// Using BulkInsert on parent then child
using (var db = new MyDBContext())
{
    db.BulkInsert(categories);
    db.BulkInsert(categories.SelectMany(x => x.Items);
}
```